# Converting String field to a custom datetime format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, datetime, format

I have a field which is a string that contains a date and time, what I do is I substring the field so I could only get the date, where the output looks like this:

```
2015-03-05 01:00
```

But I need to convert this to a date format similar to this:

```
05-Mar-2015 01:00
```

How do I convert it in SQL Server? This is my current syntax:

```
SELECT Convert(nvarchar(50),SUBSTRING(TT.FlightArrDate,1,10))+' '+Convert(nvarchar(5),SUBSTRING(TT.FlightArrDate,12,16))as actDateT from tabl1
```

Is it possible for me to change the date format and at the same time retain the time that it is being concatenated into?

- I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: What's the format of the original string? YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: the format of the string is this: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000

Comment: if it's 2012/2014, check the FORMAT function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query**

```
DECLARE @dt VARCHAR(20) = '2015-03-05 01:00'

SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST(@dt AS DATETIME),106),' ','-')
+' '
+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST(@dt AS DATETIME),108) AS actDateT;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like this:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(20) = '2015-03-05 01:00'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CAST(@str AS DATETIME),13)
```

But without character "-" between date parts. Is symbol "-" necessary in your result?

Comment: Apparently no. The data is being sent by a third party so it's in that format. We wanted to change the format but changing it would require so much bureaucracy that we just stuck to this format (date fields are in string format).

Answer (score 1):

Changing the datetime string into a real datetime, then formatting from there should give you what you want.

```
declare @d varchar(32)
set @d = '2015-03-05 01:00'

SELECT Convert(nvarchar(50),SUBSTRING(@d,1,10))+' '+Convert(nvarchar(5),SUBSTRING(@d,12,16)) as actDateT 

select format(convert(datetime, @d, 120), 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm')
```

Comment: `FORMAT` function will work for `SQL Server 2012` and `SQL Server 2014`.

Comment: Nope - SQL Server 2012 onwards as @Ullas said.